# Transformar un menu a responsive, problema con el logo

Tags: html, css

estoy haciendo un menu fijo, pero el problema es que la imagen cuando voy cambiando las resoluciones se mueve donde no debe, he subido el código [a este link](https://mega.nz/#!s14AWCSb!xHtPifcEcR5MgnNvUNgGlaeapEK9GDLCJEp4hw9cZMM) (el index es router.html) ya que es mucho y tuve unos problemas para ponerlo en una web, mis disculpas.

El problema radica en que al observar una resolución más chica en el navegador, para que se vea la vista movil, la imagen se ve más abajo de lo normal.
En cambio, si lo veo desde un movil, se ve bien.
[image: Se ve mas abajo de lo normal.]

Además al hacer click en la parte de la derecha se muestra de esta manera:
[image: Se salta todo el cuadro amarillo]
Se salta todo el cuadro amarillo. Intenté toda la tarde ver cuál podría ser el problema, pero aún no logro saber como solucionarlo. Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida, muchas gracias de antemano.

Acá hay un trozo del código:

```
        <header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" style="
    background: white;
    height: 15vh;
    ">
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">


    <button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"
    aria-expanded="false" class="navbar-toggle collapsed ">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>

    <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand hidden-xs hidden-sm" style="padding: 0px 15px; margin-left:30%;"><img src="img/logo.jpg" class="hidden-xs hidden-sm" style="height: 13vh;"></a>
    <a class="navbar-header" href="index.html"><img src="img/logo-s.jpg" style="height:60px; weight:auto; margin-top:5%; margin-left:5%; margin-bottom:5%;" class="visible-xs visible-sm"/></a></div>



<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
<br class="visible-xs"/><br class="visible-xs"/>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" style="
padding-top: 2vh;
padding-right: 4rem;
color: black;">
<li><a href="router.html" v-if="personaLogueada">Mi Perfil</a></li>
<li><a href="routerf6f2.html?page=blog" class="btn btn-xs btn-warning btn-circle"><span class="fa fa-rss hidden-xs"></span><span class="visible-xs">Blog</span></a></li>
<li><a target="new" href="mailto:gestion@graphicsexecutive.com" class="btn btn-xs btn-warning btn-circle"><span class="fa fa-envelope-o hidden-xs"></span><span class="visible-xs">Contacto</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</nav>
</header>
```

Y un poco de css:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:500,600,700,100,800,900,400,200,300);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playball);

[v-cloak] {
  display: none;
}
.botoneraEmpresa {
    margin: 20px;

}
.botonEmpresa {
    top: 50%;
    padding: 7%;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  /* background-color: rgb(231,166,26); */
    min-height: 100px;
    cursor: pointer;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}

body, html{
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility !important;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased !important;
}

@media (min-width: 1200px){
    .container {
    width: 1100px;
    }
}

h1{
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

h2{
    line-height: 20px;
    margin:  0;
}

h4 {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: rgb(47, 147, 123);
}
p{
    font-size: 13px;
}

a {
    color: #ffffff;
    transition: all 0.8;
}
a:hover,
a:focus{
    color: white;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.clearfix:after {
     visibility: hidden;
     display: block;
     font-size: 0;
     content: " ";
     clear: both;
     height: 0;
     }
.clearfix { display: inline-block; }
* html .clearfix { height: 1%; }
.clearfix { display: block; }

/* Home Style */
#tf-home{
    background: url(../img/back-login.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    color: #cfcfcf;
}

#tf-home .overlay{
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,13) 17%, rgba(255,255,255,0.66) 35%, rgba(255,255,255,0.55) 62%, rgba(255,255,255,0.2) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(17%,rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(35%,rgba(255,255,255,0.66)), color-stop(62%,rgba(255,255,255,0.55)), color-stop(100%,rgba(255,255,255,0.2))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 17%,rgba(255,255,255,0.66) 35%,rgba(255,255,255,0.55) 62%,rgba(255,255,255,0.2) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 17%,rgba(255,255,255,0.66) 35%,rgba(255,255,255,0.55) 62%,rgba(255,255,255,0.2) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 17%,rgba(255,255,255,0.66) 35%,rgba(255,255,255,0.55) 62%,rgba(255,255,255,0.2) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 27%,rgba(255,255,255,0.66) 35%,rgba(255,255,255,0.55) 62%,rgba(255,255,255,0.2) 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#cc000000', endColorstr='#66000000',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    height: auto;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

.content {
    padding: 15% 0 5% 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 1vh;
}
/* Navigation */
#tf-menu {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
    color: #fff !important;
    padding: 2% 0;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}
#sticky {
    padding: 0.5ex;
    background-color: #333;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 2em;
    border-radius: 0.5ex;
}
#tf-menu.stick {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10000;
    background: #222222;
    padding: 1% 0;
}
#tf-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    color: gray;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 700;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

#tf-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
#tf-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
    color: #2F937B;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.logo {
    font-family: 'Playball', cursive;
}

#tf-service{
    padding: 7% 0;
}

.media-left.media-middle i {
    padding: 20px 30px 20px 0;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: rgb(47, 147, 123);

}

.media-body h4 {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: rgb(47, 147, 123);
}

#tf-portfolio{
    background: #f1f1f1;
    padding: 5%  0 8% 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.section-title hr{
    border-color: rgb(47, 147, 123);
    width: 60px;
}

.section-title h2{ font-weight: 700;}
button.btn,
a.btn {
    transition: all 0.5s;
}
button.btn.btn-primary.my-btn,
a.btn.btn-primary.my-btn {
    background: #2F937B;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-radius: 0px;
    border-width: 2px;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 12px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-weight: 600;
}
button.btn.btn-primary.my-btn:hover,
a.btn.btn-primary.my-btn:hover{
    background: #FFFFFF;
    color: #2F937B;
    border-color: transparent;
}
button.btn.btn-primary.my-btn.dark:hover,
a.btn.btn-primary.my-btn.dark:hover{
    background: #222222;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-color: transparent;
}
a.btn.btn-primary.my-btn2 {
    background: rgba(47, 147, 123, 0);
    border-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 0px;
    border-width: 2px;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 12px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

a.btn.btn-primary.my-btn2:hover{
    background: #2F937B;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-color: transparent;
}

ul.cat.list-inline li a {
    border: 1px solid #2F937B;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    font-size: 11px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    color: #2F937B;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}

ul.cat.list-inline li a:hover{
    background: #2F937B;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.space{ padding: 20px}
.toppadding{ padding-top: 30px}
.nopadding{ padding:  0;}

#tf-about{
    background: url(../img/back-registro.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    color: #222222;
}

#tf-about .overlay{
    height: auto;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    padding: 10% 0;
}

#tf-why-me{
    background: url(../img/i3.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    color: #222222;
}

#tf-why-me .overlay{
    height: auto;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    padding: 5% 0;
}
ul.why-me li{
    margin: 10px 0;
}
#tf-contact{
    background: url(../img/i1.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding: 5% 0;
    text-align: center;
}

form#contact {
    padding: 5%;
    background: #f1f1f1;
    outline: 6px solid rgba(34, 34, 34, 0.08);
}

#tf-contact input.form-control {
    height: 40px;
}

#tf-contact .form-control{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 16px 12px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: #555;
    background-color: #FFF;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid #FFF;
    border-radius: 0;
    border-top: 2px solid transparent;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-transition: none;
    -o-transition: none;
    transition: all 0.8s;
}
#tf-contact .form-control:focus,
#tf-contact .form-control:hover{
    border-top: 2px solid #2F937B;
}
nav#tf-footer {
    background: #222222;
    background-image: url(../img/franja.jpg);
    padding: 10px 0;
    color: #f1f1f1;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #000000;
}
nav#tf-footer a:hover {
    color: #CCC;
}

.modal-footer {text-align: center !important;}
.modal-header, .modal-footer{background-color:transparent !important;background-image:url('../img/franja-50.jpg') !important;background-position:center center;}
/* .navbar-collapse {background-color:transparent !important;background-image:url('../img/white-50.png') !important;} */
.navbar-collapse {
/* background-color: #333; */
/* background-image: url(../img/white-50.png) !important; */
}


.btn-ejec{color:#fff !important;background: #EC971F !important;border-color:#F2B662 !important;}
.btn-ejec:focus,.btn-ejec:hover{color:#fff !important;background: #F2B662 !important;border-color:#EC971F !important;}
.btn-ejecucion{color:#fff !important;background: #EC971F !important;border-color:#F2B662 !important;}
.btn-ejecucion:focus,.btn-influencia:hover{color:#fff !important;background:#F2B662 !important;border-color:#EC971F !important;}
.btn-influencia{color:#fff !important;background: #F57030 !important;border-color:#F89B6E !important;}
.btn-influencia:focus,.btn-influencia:hover{color:#fff !important;background:#F89B6E !important;border-color:#F57030 !important;}
.btn-relacion{color:#fff !important;background: #B973FF !important;border-color:#CE9DFF !important;}
.btn-relacion:focus,.btn-relacion:hover{color:#fff !important;background:#CE9DFF !important;border-color:#B973FF !important;}
.btn-pensamiento{color:#fff !important;background: #00A67C !important;border-color:#4CC1A3 !important;}
.btn-pensamiento:focus,.btn-pensamiento:hover{color:#fff !important;background:#4CC1A3 !important;border-color:#00A67C !important;}

.etiquetas .btn{width:220px !important;cursor:default;}
.texto-collapsado{height:auto !important;white-space: pre-wrap !important;}
.card-body{width:210px !important;height:120px !important;white-space: pre-wrap !important;}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px){
    .btn-circle{color:white !important;}
    .btn-circle:hover{color: #2F937B !important;}
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px){
    .btn-circle {width: 30px;height: 30px;border-radius: 15px;color:white !important;padding:8px !important;margin:8px 2px !important;line-height: 1px !important;text-align:center !important;}
    .btn-circle:hover{color: #2F937B !important;}
}
#fortalezasGallup{font-size:0.8em !important;}



header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 15vh;
    z-index: 3;
/*    position: fixed; */

}


.logo1 {
  max-height: 100%;
max-width: 50%;
height: auto;
}




@media only screen and (max-width: 769px){

  nav .menus {
        position: fixed;
        width: 87%;
        line-height: 100px;
        z-index:3;

  }

  nav .menus_der {
    position: absolute;
    right: 80px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 85px;

  }

  .fondo_menu {
    background-color:lightblue;

  }

  .logo_1 {
        line-height: 60px;
        position: fixed;
        /* float: left;*/
        margin: -26px 46px;
        color: #fff;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 20px;
        letter-spacing: 2px;z-index:3;
  }


}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px){
  nav .menus {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index:3;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px){
  nav .menus {
    position: fixed!important;
    width: 100%!important;
    z-index:3!important;
    }
}

nav ul menus {
      line-height: 60px!important;
      list-style: none!important;
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)!important;
      overflow: hidden!important;
      color: #fff!important;
      padding: 0!important;
      text-align: right!important;
      margin: 0!important;
      padding-right: 40px!important;
      transition: 1s!important;z-index:3!important;
}

nav.blacks ul {
      background: #161616;
}

nav ul li menus {

      padding: 16px 40px;
position: right;
}

nav ul li a {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #fff;
      font-size: 16px;
}


.menu{
  background:#161616;
}

.menu-icon {
      line-height: 60px;
      width: 100%;
      background: #161616;
      text-align: right;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      padding: 15px 24px;
      cursor: pointer;
      color: #fff;
      display: none;
}




.box {
  transition: box-shadow .3s;
  width: auto;
  height: calc(auto+500px);
  margin: calc(auto+500px);
  border-radius:10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
opacity: 1;


}

.box1 {
  transition: box-shadow .3s;
  width: auto;
  height: calc(auto+500px);
  margin: calc(auto+500px);
  border-radius:10px;
  padding-bottom: 10%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
opacity: 1;


}

.box:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(33,33,33,.9);
}
.box1:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(33,33,33,.9);
}


.navbar-toggle {
  z-index:1!important;
}

.navbar.navbar-default {
  padding: 10px 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  border: none;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a,
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
  color: white;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-collapse {
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontre por que sucede esto, dentro de:

```
<div class="navbar-header">
```

Esta la imagen

```
<a class="navbar-header" href="index.html"><img src="img/logo-s.jpg" 
style="height:60px; weight:auto; margin-top:5%; margin-left:5%; margin-bottom:5%;" 
class="visible-xs visible-sm"/></a></div>
```

Por el margin-top:5% la imagen queda muy abajo.

Y para que el menu aparezaca bien debes eliminar:

```
<br class="visible-xs"/>
<br class="visible-xs"/>
```

A la lista:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" style="
padding-top: 2vh;
padding-right: 4rem;
color: black;
">
```

Debes eliminarle los dos padding y asiganrle a la lista UL margin-top: 0 !important;

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias! Tengo una pregunta más, cuando empiezo a navegar por la web con el boton del menu abierto, se nota que faltaría un fondo para que se vea mejor, como lo harías?

Comment: Yo le quitaria ala etqueta nav el padding-top:                                         
     <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" style="
     background: white; height: 15vh;">                                                                          y al contenedor que tiene la clase container-fluid le agregaria la imagen con la propiedad:                                                                                                     
     background-image: url("");

Comment: Cuando a la web se le hace un zoom de 150 y 175%, se nota que la imagen se mueve, a que imagen corresponde eso y como se arreglaría?

Comment: gracias! lo intentaré como comentas

Comment: Es la misma imagen a la que le quitamos el margin-top , la imagen se mueve un poco por que el porcentaje del margin-left no es el mismo que en el zoom de 100% ya que las proporciones cambian. okk espero te salga todo bien